# The particle は (wa)

Tags: particle-は

I'm studying Japanese with みんなの日本語. In one page there are this two examples:

- にちようびは　なにを　しましたか.
- どようび　なにを　しましたか.

Why one of them have the particle は and the other hasn't? It's a mistake or something?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't a mistake. It is omitted は. We often omit a postpositional particle.

For example, 昨日(は),学校に行った, 明日どこ(へ)行く?, 何(を)食べようか?, etc.

Comment: Oh, I didn't know that the particles could be omitted. Thanks

Comment: @STKOscar (To all, please correct me if I'm inaccurate) Would like to add that sometimes, omitting the particle は can change the meaning. If your friend was already talking to you or asking you about yesterday, it would make sense for you to use は: 「きのうは　なにを　しましたか。」 「きのうは、がっこうにいった、...」 If you were speaking without きのう already being an established topic, you could say 「きのう　がっこうにいった、...」